# Realtek HD audio drivers installation

Tags: audio

I am a new eOS user and I have never used linux before.

My issue is that my speakers don't work (headphones do). I use MSI A88XM-E35 V2 motherboard with Chipset integrated by Realtek® ALC887 and my speakers are Genius SW-2.1 385.

On Windows, I had installed Realtek HD audio drivers from motherboard manufacturer site and when I first plugged those speakers, it didn't work. The 3.5mm jack comes from subwoofer, but when the software auto sellected subwoofer output type, there was no sound. I had to sellect "Front speaker out" to make it work.

Now, in eOS,the speakers don't work. I decided to install Realtek drivers on linux too. I also like sound equalization so I want to do so even if there was another solution to make those speakers work.

Sooo I downloaded this `/home/user/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18` (I can't hyperlink couse it was from official Realtek web and the [link](https://captcha.realtek.com/captcha/get/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyRW1haWwiOiJ0b25kYS5ub3ZhazIwMDNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZW5jb2RlX2lkIjoiNWNkMzMzMGU4ZmZlMTcyMGZmOTFhZmRkIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU3MzQ1MDM4LCJleHAiOjE1NTczNDUzMzh9.OTW81jPhBDDROjpvIlHwileDvK61jNiedqNi5HMSvG0) was somehow limited - only i was able to use it). It seems like it's made for Ubuntu and it's based on ALSA drivers. They also included pdf installation guide and that's where i got stuck.

*Config compile environment

./configure

This will check your system which compile capabilities is.

If you want to compile the HDA driver part only, please follow belowing.

./configure --with-cards=had-intel*

The `./configure` command manifestly cannot be executed.

Anyway, I would appreciate any help/tip very much even if it wouldn't solve the driver installation issue. If you know how to make my speakers work please help I will be very happy and thankful.

Comment: Don't do that. The realtek drivers are part of your system already. The issue is most likely that the speakers are muted. Check it with `alsamixer` on the command line

Comment: [screenshot](https://mega.nz/#!5ZJQnS6C!fGyGCqJpElyPPVOJbupklWbq36E5LSmOxWV1cM-fSow) Thank you. I have maxed all  audio, but speakers still don't work.

Comment: Nvm, now it works. I had to change channel mode. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: No problem, I just answered the same so that the question doesn't appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. The realtek drivers are part of your system already. The issue is most likely that the speakers are muted. Check it with `alsamixer` on the command line